# Картинки в Google Chrome расширении

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

Пишу расширение для браузера Google Chrome. С помощью jQuery необходимо, на страницу одного сайта, добавлять блок `<div>`, который при нажатии будет что-то выполнять.

И вроде бы все уже работает, но возникло желание, применить CSS стили, что бы все выглядело посимпатичнее. Это тоже сделал, но при попытке добавить `background-image` к `<div>` столкнулся с проблемой, стили попросту не видят картинку в файлах плагина, а пытаются подгрузиться с того сайта, к которому писал расширение.

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: Можно загрузить картинку в сеть и дать на неё абсолютную ссылку.

Comment: Да... Я тоже подумал, что так будет намного легче, чем разбираться с расширениями для Google Chrome.